# Construct a BST from Set

Tags: java

I am trying to find an effective way to construct a binary search tree from a Set. I can do it using iterators, but I think this is not the most effective way. What is the proper way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I thinks you should paste your code for better discuss.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<String> from = new HashSet<>();
from.add("3");
from.add("2");
from.add("1");
Set<String> tree =new TreeSet<>(from);
```